# Asking someone's age

Tags: word-choice, phrase

There are several expressions to ask someone's age. That which I am most familiar with is “他几岁？”. However, I am informed that this can only be used for children (I think the problem is the 几， which implies a small number). How can I ask someone's age if they are an adult?  Or perhaps asking how old someone was when something happened?

For example:

- How old is he (e.g. your father) now?
- How old was she when the accident happened?
- How old are you? (say, in the hospital, a nurse might ask a patient)

Comment: search web using e.g. "asking s.o.'s age in Chinese"

Comment: As a side note, some people may prefer not asking ages directly: They use "你属什么的" to ask for 生肖 and then guess one's age based on it.

Comment: 看起来好年轻啊，如果对方愿意回答的话，可能会说都已经40了。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to ask someone's age and they vary from neutral to very polite. "他几岁" implies that the answer is within 1-9 range, since 几 should not be used for numbers greater than 9.

As for other ways to ask the age question (all of them apply to adults):

- 你多大? - neutral
- 您多大年纪? - polite, usually used for eldery people
- 您贵庚？ - very polite and very formal

Comment: Should I say 你年纪多大 or 你多大年纪?

Comment: I am fairly certain that both are ok.

Comment: Also, it might be politer to add a *今年* when asking.

Answer (score 2):

The answer up there is good. I just want to add a little bit about how a nurse ask your age. In the hospital or police station or other kinds of bureaux, you are usually asked "您/你的年龄是多少？"or just "多少岁？".